# where does ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT comes from if i have it in both launch.json and launchSettings.json file for a dotnet core app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

It looks by default the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is defined in two places for a dotnet core mvc application that's created using the `dotnet new` command.

Why is this defined in both places? does one override the other?

Comment: I used command `dotnet new mvc` and it created only launchSettings.json file. I have .NET CORE 2.1 What version are you using?

Comment: @yW0K5o but when you generate asset for build and debug it creates a net folder called .vscode and creates a launch.json file inside of it which also contains ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in it.

Comment: I checked and couldn't see a `.vscode` folder.

Comment: it only creates the .vscode folder after you generate asset for build and debug.

Comment: This screams XY problem to me. What is the actual issue? Is the right environment value not coming through? You shouldn't really be modifying either of these because they have no purpose other than in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you are testing in VS Code instead of VS.

`launchSettings.json` is used to configure .net core project no matter whether it is in VS Code.

`launch.json` is specific to VS Code which is used to run .net core when launching from VS Code.

The settings from `launch.json` will override the value from `launchSettings.json`.